# Entering US after H1B petition start date but before employment start date

Tags: usa, immigration, h1-visa

I currently work for Company X on H1B and am planning to switch jobs to Company Y. Company Y has already filed for an H1B petition (under premium processing) for me which has also already been approved and I've received an I-797 with a begin date of Nov.16. My Company X's H1B peition is also going to be active for another year.

I plan to work for Company X until Dec.2 and then quit and leave the country on Dec.3. My start date with Company Y is Jan.4. I plan to the return to the US on Dec. 18. Is it ok to re-enter on that date considering my employment with Company Y doesn't begin until Jan 4?

Comment: Can't you stay on the old company's payroll as on leave (unpaid) until Jan 4th?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.

Comment: Do not think you can be on 2 different h1b's at the same time